# asp.net- Highlight cell in listview

Tags: asp.net, listview, conditional-statements

I have this piece of code which works fine and highlights the label. However, I want it to highlight the entire cell not just the label.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
protected void HighLight_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        Label TotalTimeLabel = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("TotalTime");
        if (TotalTimeLabel != null)
        {
            Decimal Total;
            if (Decimal.TryParse(TotalTimeLabel.Text, out Total) == true)
            {
                if (Total > (Decimal)1.5)
                {
                    TotalTimeLabel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    TotalTimeLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code for the table is below

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnItemDataBound="HighLight_ItemDataBound" >
        <LayoutTemplate>
             <table cellpadding="1" class="TableCSS" runat="server" id="tblProducts">
              <tr runat="server" style="background-color:lightgrey">
               <th runat="server">enNotificationNoNI</th>
               <th runat="server">TotalTime</th>
               <th runat="server">TPTIMEIN</th>
               <th runat="server">Status</th>
              </tr>
              <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr runat="server" class="TableData">
             <td>
              <asp:Label ID="enNotificationNoNI" runat="Server" Text='<%#Eval("enNotificationNoNI") %>' />
             </td>
             <td>
              <asp:Label ID="TotalTime" runat="Server" Text='<%#Eval("TotalTime") %>' />
             </td>
             <td>
              <asp:Label ID="TPTIMEIN" runat="Server" Text='<%#Eval("TPTIMEIN") %>' />
             </td>
             <td>
              <asp:Label ID="Status" runat="Server" Text='<%#Eval("Status") %>' />
             </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: can you post aspx page code ?

Comment: Added the table it applies to, I was hoping it would be a simple switching of context but I'm having a lot of trouble with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

For entire row

```
Control ctrl = TotalTimeLabel.Parent.Parent;
HtmlTableRow tblrw = (HtmlTableRow)ctrl;
tblrw.BgColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red.Name;
```

For one cell

```
Control ctrl = TotalTimeLabel.Parent;
HtmlTableCell tblcl = (HtmlTableCell)ctrl;
tblcl.BgColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red.Name;
```

let me know whether this works :)

Comment: Just gave it a try, it's not working though. No errors

Comment: Just had another look at it, my style sheet was interfering with it. However, this highlights the entire row! Any Idea to just highlight the cell??

Comment: OK I updated my code, Please Check and If it works mark it as answer